# How can you use indexOf() method of ArrayList to

Tags: java, arraylist

This is homework. I have a working program but it is not fully working as intended. The goal is to create a Solitaire class that is a basic solitaire like game. No colors no suits just integers. Integers 1-15 is the cards max. 
piles = new ArrayList()  // instance variable
By initializing the constructor of the ArrayList to a random number of piles via Math.random(), this starts the game.
My issue is with the end of the game. The game is over when we have 5 piles containing sizes of 1,2,3,4,5 **in any order**.
I have my over() function checking by comparing to an array, but that checks only in the exact order 1,2,3,4,5.
My professor says the following 
"ArrayList Java library methods can make this lab too easy. So with piles you may use
only these library methods: constructor; add(); size(); set(); get(); remove();
indexOf(); toString().

over()
Return true if the solitaire is over, false otherwise.
The solitaire is over when the piles have size 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, in any order. (It can be
shown that you always end up with such a configuration.)
Hint: use indexOf()."

I have been attempting to use indexOf() in this application but I cannot see how that method will be able to used to check sizes of piles in any order. It just gets the index of whatever element in that list, so it isn't making sense to me.

here is the solitaire tester class source code that I cannot change:

```
public class SolitaireTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Solitaire s = new Solitaire();

    System.out.println("Start: " + s.toString());

    int rounds = 0;
    while (!s.over()) {
        s.round();
        ++rounds;
        System.out.println(rounds + ": " + s.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("Rounds: " + rounds);
}
}
```

and here is part of my solitaire class code, the over() method

```
public boolean over()
{

int[] perfectPiles = {1,2,3,4,5};
boolean result = true;



for (int i = 0; i < piles.size(); i++)
{
    if(perfectPiles[i] != piles.get(i))

   {
        result = false;
        break;
    }
}
return result;
}
```

again my question is how could i use indexOf() to check against perfectPiles in a boolean sense so that the order of the size of the piles does not matter, as long as it contains the elements 1,2,3,4,5. Again we cannot use contains() method. Thank you, I would appreciate any help! I can post more of my code if needed, just didn't want a peer to copy all of my code.

Comment: What does `piles` look like ?

Comment: You need to compare against the size it seems, not the i-th item, and you need to check all permutations unless you sort the piles by size before.

Comment: @maraca I think OP has misused the word "size" considering OPs professor has hinted to use indexOf() method, surely that means you only need to check if that item is contained in the list rather than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

> again my question is how could i use indexOf() to check against
>   perfectPiles in a boolean sense so that the order of the size of the
>   piles does not matter, as long as it contains the elements 1,2,3,4,5.
>   Again we cannot use contains() method.

Firstly, let's go over the purpose of the `indexOf()` method which you want to use.

- [**public int indexOf(Object o)**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) -

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in
>   this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More
>   formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null
>   : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

With that in mind, your "professor" wants you to use `indexOf()` because it's quite similar to the `contains()` method in a way, which you've stated that it's is not permitted for this exercise of yours. By, using `indexOf()` we can agree that if it returns `-1` then it's **not** contained in the list and if it returns any other number then **it is** contained within the list.

Another important point which you've stated is:

> The solitaire is over when the piles have size 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, in
>   any order. (It can be shown that you always end up with such a
>   configuration.) Hint: use indexOf()."

With all that in mind, change your current solution:

```
public boolean over(){
     int[] perfectPiles = {1,2,3,4,5};
     boolean result = true;

     for (int i = 0; i < piles.size(); i++){
          if(perfectPiles[i] != piles.get(i)){
              result = false;
              break;
          }
     }

     return result;
}
```

to this:

```
public boolean over(){
     int[] perfectPiles = {1,2,3,4,5};

     for (int i = 0; i < perfectPiles.length; i++){
          if(piles.indexOf(perfectPiles[i]) == -1) return false;
     }

     return true;
}
```

Comment: if you've got any further questions feel free to notify me here.